# Position navbar below header image

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a full-screen image when a user enters my web page, and then once he scrolls down to show the navbar. I am currently struggling to get that,I have tried using margin-top on the navbar or negative margin on the header and that has not worked either.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
      <div id="header"></div> 

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">About <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Menu</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <script src="main.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
    background-image: url(../images/pasta.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:  0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
    padding-bottom: 70px;

}

h1{
   font-family: Damion; 
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: white;

}

navbar{
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take the height of the view-port you can just use css 
by make changes below 
change this :

```
<pre>
#header{
    background-image: url(../images/pasta.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:  0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;   
    padding-bottom: 70px;

}
</pre>
```

to this :

```
<pre>
#header{
    background-image: url(../images/pasta.jpg);
height:100vh;

} 

</pre>
```

or you can use js like window.innerHeight or jquery $(window).height()